# how to store htmltable into session variable

Tags: c#, .net

i have a html table which i want to pass to another page using session variable,how can it be done? I have tried this

```
Session["sumtable"] = (HtmlTable)htab;
```

Its not working...

On the other page
.aspx

```
<table id="tblsum" runat="server"></table>
```

.cs

```
if (Session["sumtable"] != null)
                {
                    tblsum = (HtmlTable)Session["sumtable"];
                }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not working? You should be able to store an HTML table in session in the same way as you would anything else...

Comment: Yes its not showing on the other page.

Comment: Well it will not show up automagically!!! What are you doing on the other page to get the table.

Comment: Have you checked, that the table is being properly stored ?

Comment: So is your code passing the null check? Are you adding tblsum to the page somehow? Have you checked what tblsum contains (ie that it is an HtmlTable)?

Comment: yes, and when i do quickwatch its showing exceptions innerhtml ..something

Comment: Its passing null check..

Comment: Post the full exception please, and the property of tblsum that is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Page Source
            Session["tbl"] = dt.Rows; // table id = td
            Response.Redirect("WebForm4.aspx");

            // page Destination
            HtmlTableRowCollection tr = (HtmlTableRowCollection)Session["tbl"];

            foreach (HtmlTableRow t in tr)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(t); // table id = td
            }
```

Comment: its giving exception..Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: dont know why im having this exception.. Everything is like you have posted.

Comment: By the way i took a htmltable object and store session variable into it on the second page, after that i add it to a div like div1.controls.add(htmltab) and it worked. Thank you guys for your support..